SQL String Manipulation - add character to beginning and end of each input
I'm compiling a UDF in SQL (Snowflake).  One of the inputs to the UDF is a string. It takes the form of the following:
SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_func(arg1, 'abc1, xyz2, 123a', arg3))

I want to process the string within the function body to include ''%' at the start and '%'' at the end of each entry [separated by a comma and space (', ')].  And also remove the preceding and ending apostrophe (') of the string.
Ultimately, I wish to utilise this as an input to a LIKE ANY for a WHERE condition.  Example...
WHERE col LIKE ANY ('%abc1%', '%xyz2%', '%123a%')

EDIT:  Appreciate there may likely be a numerous ways of doing this, something as succinct and easily readable (that I can implement inside the SQL function [e.g. not calling an anciliary function]) as possible would be great.  Help in any form however is most welcomed.

If you change your input format to '.*(abc1|xyz2|123a).*', you could use a simple rlike
where col rlike ARG2

If you'd rather modify your input to work with an rlike operator, you could do
where col rlike concat('.*',replace(replace(ARG2,', ','|'),'_','.'),'.*')


Here is the SQL solution
select rtrim(listagg('\'%'||trim(y.value)||'%\','),',')
from (
      select split(arg2,',') x, 
      from <table>
     ), lateral flatten(input=>x) y  


you can assign the result of this sql to your arg2 and pass it to your function
tested with
with s as (
SELECT 'abc1, xyz2, 123a' arg2
)
select rtrim(listagg('\'%'||trim(y.value)||'%\','),',')
from (
      select split(arg2,',') x, 
      from s
      ), lateral flatten(input=>x) y 

result
'%abc1%','%xyz2%','%123a%'


This would still compare to a single string and essentially translate to col like $$'%abc1%','%xyz2%','%123a%'$$
